# Google Chrome doesn’t allow to write JavaScript in main HTML pages, so how can I use an `onclick` function with my button?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

How to code in such a way so when you click on the “Extract” button it will run the function `DisplayRadioValue`?

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  var str = $("#inputurl").val();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()"> 
  Extract
</button>
```

I tried to use

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", displayRadioValue)
```

But it dosen’t work. Using `.addEventListener` throws the following errors:

> ```
> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at popup.js:85
> ```

Overall, the file in Google Chrome is working but when I load the extension and try to run then it shows these errors.

Comment: Your button does not have the `myButton` ID. Also, [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905)? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: in html you should do: ```<button id="myButton">button</button>``` than in js: ```document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunc);``` click will run function 'myFunc'

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use jQuery, then you need to add jQuery script to the html.
Also, you'll need some element with an id you are looking for that will take a value.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener("click", displayRadioValue);

function displayRadioValue() {
  var str = $("#inputurl").val();
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='button' type="button" > 
  Extract
</button>

<input id='inputurl' value='www.google.com'>
```

Comment: if i run the file in google chrome it's working but when i load the extension and try to run then it shows the following errors 

" Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at popup.js:85

Comment: ok, i've updated the snippet and removed the onclick event and added a listener instead.  see if that works with the extension

Comment: im using jquery and tried your technique but still it give same error 

" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at popup.js:89 "

Comment: if i do this 
<button id="myButton" type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()"> 
        Extract
    </button>

code start to work due to "onclick" but no in extension side

Comment: what extension are you using?

Comment: it's a web scrapper extract data from the web

Comment: but which one? I'll need to load it to see what's going on

Comment: brother send me your email i will send you files and details

Answer (score 0):

if you not use jquery you can do it like this:

```js
const displayRadioValue = () => {
  const value = document.querySelector("#inputurl").value;
  console.log(value);
}

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", displayRadioValue);
```

```html
<input id='inputurl' value='www.google.com' />
<button id="myButton">button</button>
```